# How to pivot longer data , while keep first few rows without duplication?

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse, tidyr, data-wrangling

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA, 'A', 'B'), col2=c('year1', 'year2', 'year3', 'year4', 10,20))
```

How to wrangle this data into following

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c( 'A',  'B'),
                  col2=c( 'year1', 'year1'), 
                  col3=c( 'year2', 'year2'),
                  col4=c( 'year3', 'year3'), 
                  col5=c( 'year4', 'year4'), 
                  col6=c( 10, 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr::pivot_wider` kind of does what you're looking for, but given the structure of your data, you would have to do further manipulation with it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "col2",
    names_glue = "col_{col2}",
    values_from = "col2"
  ) |> 
  mutate(
    across(matches("year"), ~replace(.x, is.na(.x), .x[1])),
    col_10 = if_else(is.na(col_10), "20", col_10)
    ) |> 
  slice(-1) |> 
  select(-col_20)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  col1  col_year1 col_year2 col_year3 col_year4 col_10
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr> 
1 A     year1     year2     year3     year4     10    
2 B     year1     year2     year3     year4     20
```

Comment: thank you a lot for your help, was using pivot longer :(, many thanks